# Why are some files not correctly installed when installing via TestFlight?

Tags: ios, ipad, distribution, over-the-air, testflight

I distribute my iOS apps to my client with TestFlight for beta-testing.

The problem is that we both experienced weird problems/behaviors with these apps when installing from TestFlight, which were fixed when uninstalling/reinstalling the apps (still from TestFlight).

I don't see anything in my code explaining why a uninstall/reinstall is required (no CoreData migrations, no change in file storage usage, or other things like this).

I'm quite confident that things will go better for end users that will upgrade their app via the App Store but :

- I still wonder if other people met the same problem
- and if I should be that confident about the fact that things will be fine when the end users will upgrade their app via the App Store.

EDIT : today, I've experienced that installing via TestFlight didn't update the new icon: the icon from the previous version was still being used => Confidence 1, TestFlight 0! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen some issues with TestFlight when pushing out updates. The fix seems to be to delete the app prior to updating.

**I've had this happen on multiple apps that I have since published to the app store** and have seen no corresponding issues when pushing out updates through the app store rather than through TestFlight.

My guess would be that there is a bit more "cleaning up" so to speak when apps are updating via the store that does not occur when updating via TF... TF/Ad-hoc installs seem to be more akin to a copy paste job rather than an update, if that makes sense.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to hear :) Thanks!

Comment: @DirtyHenry remember what the nice big green check is for if you think this is the best answer ;)

Comment: :) Don't worry, i'm just leaving the question open another few hours to know if another person can give more details (maybe some TestFlight developers are hanging around the place)

Comment: This is old, but thought I'd add that I've been having some very strange issues with TestFlight - Core Data crashing, eg. - all of which disappeared when I disabled TestFlight in my app delegate.  This kind've sucks as I love it, but being able to push out working builds to clients is slightly more important for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

I think updating the version of your project in the main plist will fix this issue.

Comment: I always did that... Unfortunately... :) Thanks