# Issue with UIWebView caching pages

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I'm loading a remote html page into a UIWebView, the page is held on my mac book pro using and made available via OS X's built in Apache server.

I've noticed that if I load the page in the UIWebView, then make changes to the page and reload it then the changes are not reflected, hence it must presumably be being cached somewhere.
I get this behavior even if I quit the app containing the UIWebView and re-launch it.

Where is the web page being cached?  Is it possible to force the UIWebView to get the latest updated page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

`[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:NSURLRequest];`

This would remove a cached response for a specific request. There is also a call that will remove all cached responses for all requests ran on the UIWebView:

`[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];`